# Video recording with cameraX 1.0.0-beta11 not working

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, video-capture, android-camerax

I am trying to record video with latest version of cameraX 1.0.0-beta11 but I am facing issue in recording it.

**Code snippet to start camera and record video.**

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun startCameraX() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(activity!!)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }

              val videoCapture=VideoCapture.Builder().setVideoFrameRate(15).build()


            val videoFile = File(
                getOutputDirectory(),
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4")
            val outputOptions = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(videoFile).build()
            videoCapture.startRecording(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity), object: VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback{
                override fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: VideoCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    Log.e("data","onVideoSaved")
                }

                override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                    Log.e("data", "onError->$message")
                }
            })

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    (this as LifecycleOwner), cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }


        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity))
    }
```

**Output directory**

```
private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
            val mediaDir = activity?.externalMediaDirs?.firstOrNull()?.let {
                File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
            return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
                mediaDir else activity!!.filesDir
        }
```

**Error - Not bound to a Camera [androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@4bd02a4]**

Please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must use 1.0.0-beta11 version or you can use the older version of CameraX library (e.g 1.0.0-beta01)?

Comment: @lincollincol I have to use latest version of camX

Comment: here is a great CameraX example with picture and video capture. I was using it, when implementing camera in the messenger at work.

https://github.com/iambaljeet/CameraXView

But example based on 1.0.0-beta01. Realy don't know about changes in new version. You can try it.

Comment: @lincollincol Thanks for the link, it works well for older versions but I need to work on latest version.

Comment: What is your issue? Can you share details about it?

Comment: @lincollincol getting error while binding videocapture

Comment: @lincollincol exact error is -> Not bound to a Camera [androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@4bd02a4]

Answer (score 0):

You must start the camera before calling the startRecording function. Basically you should output the following code in a function.

```
val videoFile = File(
    getOutputDirectory(),
    SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4")
val outputOptions = VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(videoFile).build()
videoCapture.startRecording(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity), object: VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback{
    override fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: VideoCapture.OutputFileResults) {
        Log.e("data","onVideoSaved")
    }
    override fun onError(videoCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
        Log.e("data", "onError->$message")
    }
})
```

And call it when the user clicks record button, then, when user clicks stop button you can stop recording with

```
videoCapture.stopRecording()
```

Once stopRecording function is called, if everything is ok, onVideoSaved function is gonna be called